# How to set global conf for PyFlakes?

Tags: linux, vim, python, dotfiles

My Vim is using PyFlakes to check for style errors in Python code. PyFlakes by default request that line isn't more than 79 symbols long, but our team's convention is 160 symbols. So the situation is that everyone in our team is writing long lines and PyFlakes is complaining a lot! It's possible to change line length when calling PyFlakes from command line just by passing argument. I'm looking for a way to do it in some “dotfile“ (file located in *~* dir) so it works globally and, because of that “dotfile“, also in my Vim.

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to add this to my *~/.vimrc*.

```
let g:syntastic_python_checker_args = "--max-line-length=160"
```